# Get dummy reference to an object of type given by template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, template-meta-programming

There was an `std::` templated function that allowed getting a dummy reference to an object of a given type even though that type had private constructors. I'm forgetting it, and couldn't find it on google. It was something like:

```
template<class SomeType>
void MyFunction(SomeType [& or *] defaultArg = std::that_elusive_func<SomeType>())
{}
```

Obviously the above defaultArg won't be used at runtime because it's invalid, it's just for template metaprogramming purposes.

I can't seem to remember it. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want std::declval?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval

.....